# html5 animation: canvas clearing works but everything is redrawn

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I want a circle to move around my canvas.

So for each frame of the animation, I clear the canvas and draw a new circle with new origin coordinates.

Executing my code step by step, I can see that the `clearRect` function works well but every time the canvas is redrawn, the new circle and all the previous circles are drawn, including a straight lines from the first circle center to the new circle center.

File `index.html`:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>my website</title>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="init();">
      <canvas class="circle" id="pinkCircle" width="400" height="400"
        style="border:1px solid pink;">
      </canvas>
      <script src="js/myjs.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

File `js/myjs.js`:

```
//set variables
  var canvas;
  var context;
  var myCircle = {x:50,y:100,r:20};
  //offset
  var dx = 8;
  var dy = 5;
  function init() {
    //set canvas and its context
    canvas = document.getElementById('pinkCircle');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //repeat the drawCircle function for each frame
    setInterval(drawCircle,1000);
  }
  function drawCircle() {
    //clear the canvas
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    //redraw a circle with a different origin coordinates each time
    context.beginPath;
    context.arc(myCircle.x, myCircle.y, myCircle.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
    if( myCircle.x<0 || myCircle.x>400) dx=-dx; 
    if( myCircle.y<0 || myCircle.y>400) dy=-dy;
    myCircle.x+=dx;
    myCircle.y+=dy;
  }
```

I have been through a lot of online resources but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You code is almost correct. But you made one small error:
Didn't gave round brackets in below line:

```
context.beginPath;
```

It should be:

```
context.beginPath();
```

Working [JS Bin Link](http://jsbin.com/aNEBudEC/1)

Comment: Adding the brackets fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Autoredraw property of the page? I think it must be set to false in your case.